# MYSQL moving order

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table.

I want to "cut and paste" a value from one column to another using php.  like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table1 SET a1=a2,a2='' WHERE colid=3 LIMIT 1");
```

Is it possible to do this with just a single statement as above?

Does the ordering of the elements used in "SET" part matter?

If this is not good, what is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Did you try this?  I think it should work correctly as you have typed it above.

Comment: I did not try this as I can't get to it until I get home.  Just curious :).  So the ordering of elements in the SET does work?

Comment: See http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/mysql/Order-of-Columns-in-the-SET-Clause.html

Comment: Based on other answers it sounds close enough to undefined behavior that I would stay away from it. You can just issue two updates in a transaction and achieve the same result. The transaction will guarantee isolation, locking, and ordering.

Comment: If I were you, I would sacrifice efficiency to get maintainability. This could be an ambiguous statement, and not all sql databases will execute this in a way you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html):

> The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the current (updated) col1 value, not the original col1 value. The result is that col1 and col2 have the same value. This behavior differs from standard SQL.
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```
>
> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.

Comment: I love the way they say "are generally evaluated from left to right" as opposed to no guarantee of the order...

Answer (score 1):

Tried it, works.  But like others have mentioned it is an efficiency step at the cost of maintainability.

Personally, I will be using the efficient code, since it's for a non-critical functionality.  If you want to use it, understand the risks.